# How to get the field name dynamically and update it to main table in progress

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Program:It is a just maintenance program, in this one it displays the Item Code in one frame and it prompt for the input. if you enter the item code it has to displays what are the blank fields for that record in pt_mstr and display in one frame(No need to display all blank fields, just first 4 or 5 fields enough). and also in that frame only if user want to update it update directly to main table pt_mstr.

What i tried is, i just write the code for getting blank fields using buffer handle and after that i create one temp table and displaying the fields, i strucked there itself, i am unable to update fields.

My code:

```
/*Sample Item master Maintenance Program*/
/* DISPLAY TITLE */ 
{us/mf/mfdtitle.i "3+ "} 
DEFINE VARIABLE hBuffer AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE i       AS INTEGER NO-UNDO. 
DEFINE VARIABLE j       AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hField  AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
define variable fldnm as character extent 10 no-undo.
define temp-table tt_temp no-undo
   field tt_part like pt_part
   field field1 as char extent 10. 
form
    pt_part colon 25
    with frame a side-labels width 80.
    setFrameLabels(frame a:handle).
/* DISPLAY */
view frame a.
repeat with frame a:
   prompt-for pt_part
      editing:
   /* FIND NEXT/PREVIOUS RECORD */
     {us/mf/mfnp.i pt_mstr pt_part "pt_mstr.pt_domain = global_domain and pt_part" pt_part pt_part pt_part }
     if recno <> ? then
          do:
display pt_part.
             find pt_mstr where pt_part = input pt_part and pt_domain=global_domain no-lock no-error.
               ASSIGN hBuffer = BUFFER pt_mstr:HANDLE.
               empty temp-table tt_temp.
               j = 1.
               DO i = 1 TO 10:
                ASSIGN hField = hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD(i).                                                                            
                    IF ((hField:BUFFER-VALUE = "" )) THEN                          
                          do:        
                            /*  message  hField:NAME "test" view-as alert-box.*/
                            find first tt_temp where tt_part = pt_part no-lock no-error.
                             if not avail tt_temp then
                               do:
                                create tt_temp.
                                assign
                                tt_part = pt_part
                                field1[j] = hField:NAME.
                                j = j + 1.
                               end. 
else do:
                    assign
                       field1[j] = hField:NAME.
                       j = j + 1.
                 end.
            end.
                     end.
          end.
               for  each tt_temp:
                display field1[1] field1[2] field1[3] field1[4].
                end.
    end.                                                                                                                                    
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need your temp-tables to do this? I've created an example using only the actual table (but created a fake temp-table instead). You would have to look into data error handling, data validation, transaction, locking etc before putting this into production of course.

```
/*First we need some fake data */
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttMockedData NO-UNDO
    FIELD id AS INTEGER
    FIELD dataName         AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(8)"
    FIELD dataType         AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(8)"
    FIELD dataDescrioption AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(32)".

DEFINE VARIABLE iId     AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iSearch AS INTEGER NO-UNDO LABEL "Search".

PROCEDURE createData:
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcName AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcType AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcDesc AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

    iId = iId + 1.

    CREATE ttMockedData.
    ASSIGN 
        ttMockedData.id       = iId
        ttMockedData.dataName = pcName
        ttMockedData.dataType = pcType
        ttMockedData.dataDesc = pcDesc.

END PROCEDURE.

RUN createData("Test 1", "TESTTYPE", "A TEST").
RUN createData("Test 2", "", "ANOTHER TEST").
RUN createData("", "TESTTYPE 2", "").
RUN createData("4", "", "").

/* Program starts here */
updating:
REPEAT:

    UPDATE iSearch WITH FRAME x0.
    IF iSearch > 0 THEN DO:
        FIND FIRST ttMockedData NO-LOCK WHERE ttMockedData.id = iSearch NO-ERROR.
        IF NOT AVAILABLE ttMockedData THEN DO:
            MESSAGE "Not found" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
            RETURN ERROR.
        END.
        ELSE DO:

            DISP ttMockedData WITH FRAME x1 1 COLUMNS SIDE-LABELS.

            /* Is there an empty field? - Then we update! */
            IF ttMockedData.dataName         = ""
            OR ttMockedData.dataType         = ""
            OR ttMockedData.dataDescrioption = "" THEN DO:

                DISPLAY
                    ttMockedData.dataName 
                    ttMockedData.DataType 
                    ttMockedData.dataDesc 
                    WITH FRAME x2 1 COLUMN SIDE-LABELS TITLE "Complete the data...". 

                /* This isn't working with temp-tables of course! */
                /* Just here to make sure you handle locking! */
                FIND CURRENT ttMockedData EXCLUSIVE-LOCK.

                UPDATE                                                               
                    ttMockedData.dataName WHEN ttMockedData.dataName = ""            
                    ttMockedData.DataType WHEN ttMockedData.DataType = ""            
                    ttMockedData.dataDesc WHEN ttMockedData.dataDesc = ""            
                    WITH FRAME x2.

                /* This isn't working with temp-tables of course! */
                /* Just here to make sure you handle locking! */
                FIND CURRENT ttMockedData NO-LOCK.
            END.


        END.
    END.
    ELSE LEAVE updating.
END.
```

Comment: Hi @Jensd, did you get my point clearly? if i enter item code  it will search the pt_mstr for that item and display what are the blank fields for that record and there itself if we update it will effect to pt_mstr.

Comment: @LovelyBobby I would say that my example does that - without dynamic matching of fields though (that could be added of course).

Comment: Isn't possible with dynamic matching of fields? bcz your solution i cant use in my code , will you sugget me best solution for my problem

Comment: I'm thinking that the fields you want to complete are limited and known - therefore a static solution should be viable. If they are unknown then a dynamic solution might be useful but that doesn't sound viable. You should be able to customize my example to your needs!

Comment: I don't think so @Jensd, bcz while finding the blank fields, actually there will be so many blank fields for particular record thats why i am taking 1to10 (its enough for my program), but in this also we dont know which field will be blank for particular item (for example for one recorde it may be 1, 3, 9 fields and for another 1,5) so we can not predict it should take dynamically only.